# Perl running on 1and1 server hangs when using LWP

Tags: perl

I'm using the 1and1 Windows basic hosting package and I'm trying to run some perl:

```
#generate header
my $h = HTTP::Headers->new(
                           Content_type =>  'audio/mpeg'
                          );
print $h->as_string;

#parse querystring
if (length ($ENV{'QUERY_STRING'}) > 0){
  $buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
  @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
  foreach $pair (@pairs){
       ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
       $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
       $in{$name} = $value; 
  }
}

#generate url to GET
$url = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=' . $in{'q'};

use LWP::UserAgent;

#get file
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
my $req = new HTTP::Request GET => "$url";
#$req->header('Accept' => 'text/html');
my $res = $ua->request($req);
my $content = $res->content;

print $content;
```

Basically just trying to retrieve an audio file and print it.

When I run it locally, I have no problems.  However, when I run it on my shared server (which I don't have command line access to), it simply hangs and the page won't load.

Has anyone dealt with this, or is there something I can do to debug it?  Is there any other way I could do this that might work?

Edit: Updated code:

```
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header('audio/mpeg');

#generate url to GET
#my $val = $q->param('q');
my $val = "test";
my $url = 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=en&q=' . $val;

use LWP::UserAgent;

#get file
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36');
my $req = new HTTP::Request GET => "$url";
my $res = $ua->request($req); #hangs here
my $content = $res->content;

print $content;
```

I've isolated the issue to the request call, so it must be the server configuration.

Comment: At the very least, use [CGI.pm](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) so you don't have to parse the query string yourself. Also, you never declared `%in`, so you either omitted that from your code snippet or aren't running with `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: As for debugging, do you have access to your web server's error logs? That's always the first place to look. You can also `use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);` to print errors directly to the browser (never do this in production, though).

Comment: Probably your host does not allow outgoing connections. These shared hosting companies are usually pretty serious about their bandwidth. Read their terms and support pages, they'll probably have a FAQ or something about this. If this is the case you should probably try with a client-side solution, like AJAX.

Comment: I've isolated the issue to the request call, so it must be that.  I was avoiding AJAX because I need to set the user agent.  I have some solutions that I could look into other than "borrowing" the Google translate TTS service, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html) stipulates that there must be a blank line between the response headers and the body. When you run:

```
my $h = HTTP::Headers->new(Content_type => 'text/html');
print $h->as_string;
print "foo";
```

You get:

```
Content-Type: text/html
foo
```

when what you need is:

```
Content-Type: text/html

foo
```

You can verify this by running your script on the command line. I would recommend using [CGI.pm](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) to generate your response headers (or even better, a modern web framework like [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/), [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/), or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/)). Here's how to do it with CGI:

```
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header('audio/mpeg');
# Do stuff
print $content;
```

This has the added benefit of [parsing the query string](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#FETCHING-THE-NAMES-OF-ALL-THE-PARAMETERS-PASSED-TO-YOUR-SCRIPT%3a) for you.

Comment: I'll accept this since this would probably have been an issue had I been able to get everything else to work.